# Pass arguments to the compiler via MAKE

Tags: ubuntu, unix, gcc, makefile, g++

When I try to build code:

```
make -C ./source/SomeUtil mode=release
```

it fails with an error:

> fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 35 (use
>   -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum)

It seems somehow I need to force MAKE to pass that argument to the compiler:
**-ftemplate-depth=50**

I tried to set variables **CFLAGS** and **CXXFLAGS**, but it hasn't helped at all (still get error with the ftemplate-depth=35).

```
export CFLAGS="-ftemplate-depth=50"
export CXXFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
```

Also I tried to pass CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS after MAKE, but there was no success again.

How can I force MAKE pass -ftemplate-depth=50 argument to the compiler? Thanks.

Comment: Does `make CXX='g++ -ftemplate-depth=50'` work?

Comment: Arkadiusz Drabczyk, no, it doesn't.

Comment: The solution was found by editing Makefile (so it would use variables I was trying to set).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't force make to do anything the Makefile isn't set up to accept.

Setting CXXFLAGS is the right idea but not CFLAGS. A C compiler has no idea what to do with "-ftemplate-depth=50". So only set CXXFLAGS and edit our makefile to honor CXXFLAGS set in the environment (or better extend the CXXFLAGS in the Makefile so you don't have to passit via make) and make sure it passes CXXFLAGS to the compiler.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither passing the argument:
sudo make CXXFLAGS="-ftemplate-depth=50" -C ./Source/MyUtil mode=release
nor setting it globally:
export CXXFLAGS="-ftemplate-depth=50"
sudo make -C ./Source/MyUtil mode=release

helped :(.

Comment: As it wouldn't if the Makefile simply doesn't use them.

Comment: Goswin von Brederlow, thanks for the rigth hint! I've just looked into the Makefile's content, edited it a little and now it works!